# ASP.NET hover not working

Tags: css, asp.net

I am working on creating a dropdown using [this](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20type=%22text/css%22%20href=%22http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css%22%20/%3E)stylesheet, however the hover does not work as expected. Testing is outside of ASP.NET it works fine. Any input where I could be going wrong would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
        Dropdown <i class="ion-chevron-down"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-trigger {
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-trigger i {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown-trigger:hover i {
  background-color: #99f;
}
.dropdown-trigger:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #99f;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

This is the entire code I have.

Comment: Well, it's not all the code you have. You have a file named "Site.Master" too. Indeed, the `link` element should be located in the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Seems to be working fine when i run it in visual studios. Which browser are you getting this problem in?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have css link in `head`

Comment: @NasirT I am using Chrome

Comment: Looking at the resulting HTML would be more direct.

Comment: The contents of the `<asp:Content>` tag is not included in the head.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am sorry, I am trying to wrap my head around this. If I understand it correctly, I have to include the style sheet in `head` section in the master page. Could you explain what do you mean by content is not included in the head

Comment: Check this video of my test in a asp.net page with a master page. http://screencast.com/t/Xb7rYcsk. The only change i needed to make was to add a top:30px; to join the icon and the dropdown content together.

Comment: @NasirT, did you add anything to the Master page? I am confused on how it works for you but why it doesnot have the same behavior on my machine.

Comment: In the code you've included here, you have the `link` element within the `asp:Content` tag. That `link` will be included within the `body`, not the `head`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, so I removed the link from the body and added it to the head in master (thank you for explaining that) but I still have the same behavior.

Comment: I got it to work, I was not including the other style sheet. That was a dumb mistake. 

THANK YOU all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing stylesheet reference somewhere. Add stylesheet link in your master page head tag. Also add in the styles in the master page using either `<style>..</style>` tags or add them in .css file and link that file in master page.

Here is a video showing the code in it's place in the master file and then in the content page. Everything seems to be working as expected. The only addition i made was to add `top: 30px;` in the `.dropdown-menu` class to remove the space between the icon and the dropdown menu.

Video: http://www.screencast.com/t/f85uKhdRXP0J